# Prove that if $A$ is dense in $X$ and $U$ is open then $U \subseteq \overline{A \cap U}$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

This is Exercise 4 from Section 2.2 of *Topology and Groupoids* by Brown.

**Exercise:**

> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $A \subseteq B \subseteq X$. We
> say that $A$ is *dense in* $B$ if $B \subseteq \overline A$, and $A$
> is *dense* if $\overline A = X$. Prove that if $A$ is dense in $X$ and
> $U$ is open then $U \subseteq \overline{A \cap U}$.

**More information:**

The definition of the overline/bar notation:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $A \subseteq X$. The *closure*
> of $A$ is the set $\overline A$ of points $x$ in $X$ such that every
> neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$.

**My attempt:**

Consider $x \in U$. We want to show that every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A \cap U$. Clearly every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $U$, so we just have to show that every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$. Since $A$ is dense in $X$, we know that $X \subseteq \overline A$, which can only mean that $\overline A = X$. Since $x \in X$, we see that every neighborhood of $x$ does intersect $A$, which concludes the proof.

**My concern:**

I didn't make any use of the assumption that $U$ is open, which makes me wonder if I screwed up somewhere.

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Note that we only need $A$ to be dense in $U$ for this fact to hold.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Just so I understand, you're still assuming that $U$ is open, right? I proved the result assuming that $A$ is dense in $U$ and $U$ is open. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, I just wanted to point out you did not need the full strength of $A$ being dense in $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joshua P. Swanson pointed out the key error in my proof, which was the conflation of the intersection with $A$ and $U$ with the intersection *with the intersection* $A \cap U$. However, his answer used an open set, which is not quite general enough for my purpose because I need to use any *neighborhood* of $x$, and open sets containing $x$ are only a subset of the neighborhoods of $x$. Below I prove the assertion from scratch.

Consider $x \in U$. We want to show that for any neighborhood $N$ of $x$, $N \cap (A \cap U) \neq \emptyset$. Using basic set theory, this is equivalent to showing that $(N \cap U) \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

Because $U$ is open, it is a neighborhood of $x$. One of the neighborhood axioms states that the intersection of two neighborhoods of $x$ is also a neighborhood of $x$. That means $N \cap U$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

Since $A$ is dense in $X$, $X \subseteq \overline A$, which means that $\overline A = X$.  Since $x \in X$, we see that any neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$. Particularly, the neighborhood $N \cap U$ intersects $A$, which means that $(N \cap U) \cap A \neq \emptyset$, which concludes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt has a gap. You've shown separately that every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $U$ and also intersects $A$. This is not the same as saying that every neighborhood of $U$ intersect $A \cap U$. More precisely, you've shown for all open $V \ni x$, $V \cap U \neq \varnothing$ and $V \cap A \neq \varnothing$, but you need to conclude $V \cap (U \cap A) \neq \varnothing$.

To fix it, use the fact that $V \cap U$ is open.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am a little concerned about the fact that you are using open sets, because I am supposed to use any neighborhood of $x$, and open sets containing $x$ are only a subset of neighborhoods of $x$.

Comment: @Novice Fair enough. Of course, it's trivial, and there's actually competing definitions of "neighborhood", e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067662/is-neighborhood-an-open-set). I suppose I'm used to Rudin's tradition.